# Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' with POST method,Soap request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, ntlm-authentication

Getting below error while sending a SOAP request with NTLM Authentication.

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with URI http://********. at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1581)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1533)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1336)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 54 more
```

Problem occurred when sending a  large XML request payload size. It works fine when the payload size is smaller.

Tried setting content length at header but did not worked.

Comment: What is the code that causes this error?

Comment: Especially the line that performs the authentication

Comment: public class NtlmAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
 private final String username;
 private final char[] password;
public NtlmAuthenticator(final String username, final String password) {
super();
this.username = new String(username);
this.password = password.toCharArray(); 
}
@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return (new PasswordAuthentication (username, password));
 }
public TestClass(String username, String password){
NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(username,password);
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
 }

Comment: TestWebServicesPort port = rws.getWebServicesPort();
//Below line gives 401 authentication error
 port.webRequest(new Holder(pxmlRequest), response);

Comment: You probably hit one of the open issues: https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CXF%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20~%20%22ntlm%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC